# Get list of numbers in between two columns with key

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers, between

I want to get the list of numbers in between two columns. A tables values will be used to generate more rows.

e.g
Table1:

```
Key StartNum EndNum
--- -------- ------
A   1        3
B   6        8
```

My output should be:

```
Key Num
--- ---
A   1
A   2
A   3
B   6
B   7
B   8
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971981/get-list-of-numbers-in-between-two-columns), but it didn't help me (I need rows with the key).

I need to solve this in Oracle 11g.

Comment: Geting the list of numbers was well answered on this topic http://stackoverflow.com/q/1453747/952018
But my issue was joining it with the source table where I need to send the parameters (start and end) also from the same source table.

Comment: "*But it didn't help*" is not enough information. As far as I can tell, the linke topics solve exactly your problem.

Comment: In the linked topic the result was a union of all ranges. In my case I want a join with the source table. That is why I changed the title and included the "with key" part.

Comment: Justin's answer in that question is what you are looking for as far as I can tell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971981/get-list-of-numbers-in-between-two-columns/3972132#3972132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a_horse_with_no_name-s solution would be

```
 SELECT distinct Key,(level + StartNum)-1 Num
   FROM Table1
  CONNECT BY (LEVEL +StartNum ) <= EndNum+1
  order by Key, Num
```

Output:

```
A   1                                     
A   2                                     
A   3                                     
B   6                                     
B   7                                     
B   8
```

But I'd prefer creating a global temporary table and populate it from plsql, as the above method contains subsequent decarts on the table (thus the distinct required).
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_temporary_tables_sql.htm

Comment: This solution works as it should. But with some testing we learnt that the performance degrades exponentially with the rows. Therefore as correctly mentioned by vmatyi also the best solution would be to go for a table based solution. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly adapted version of Justin's solution posted in: [get list of numbers in between two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971981/get-list-of-numbers-in-between-two-columns/3972132#3972132)

```
select key, num 
from (
  select distinct t1.key, t1.startnum + level - 1 num, t1.startnum, t1.endnum
  from table1 t1
  connect by level <= (select t2.endnum from table1 t2 where t1.key = t2.key)
) t
where num between t.startnum and t.endnum
order by key, num
```

I'm not happy with the need for the `distinct` in the inner query, but I currently don't have the time to dig deeper into this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT t.StartNum , t.StartNum , ROWNUM
FROM Table1 t , ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE ROWNUM between t.StartNum  and t.StartNum
```

Comment: This will only work if the number of objects in the database is smaller than the max. endnum in the table

Answer (score -1):

Create a store procedure in transact SQL

```
Create Procedure GetRangeFromTable 
As
Begin 

    create table #Result(           
            code varchar(50),
            num int
    )  

    Declare 
     @code varchar(50),
     @start int ,
     @end int

    DECLARE num_cursor CURSOR FOR Select * from Table1
    OPEN num_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM num_cursor 
    INTO @code, @start, @end


    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        While @start <= @end
        Begin
            Insert into #Result(code,num) Values (@code,@start)
            Set @start= @start + 1
        End 

       FETCH NEXT FROM num_cursor 
       INTO @code, @start, @end

    END

    Select * from #Result

    CLOSE num_cursor
    DEALLOCATE num_cursor

End
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But need to solve this in Oracle. I will include that in the question.

Comment: It's the same principal. I do not have oracle install it